# Fb Share Issue - invalid image content type (Wordpress Website)

Tags: wordpress, share

I am trying to share an article. The Debugger tool though seems to find the image. The error I get is Invalid Image Content-Type. Image is loaded correctly if I just go and open it from the browser.

This issue is for certain images only[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try yoast seo plugin social it is free choose your image with it and then write your website description